# How to add code into shopify page

Tags: jquery, html, css, shopify

How do I add code like the following https://codepen.io/fjenpen/pen/pROPov into only 1 of multiple shopify pages within a shopify store without breaking the existing theme?

```
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bg">
 <div class="nav">
<ul id="menu" style="list-style-type: none;">
<!-- Give your href some actual meaning -->
<li><a href="#Section1" style="text-decoration:none"><h1>Our Brands</h1></a>  </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="main">
<div id="Section1" class="content">

<p>View our brands</p>
</div>
```

Comment: use ctr+c and ctr+v

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to `Online Store > theme & edit HTML/CSS of current active theme`
From the pen you have linked, you have a requirement to add HTML, CSS & JS.

1. HTML

   - for html look the desired area liquid template and you can add HTML. You might want to create snippets and include. Use language translation instead of bare texts.
2. CSS

   - look for the theme css file, it's usually 'xxxxx.scss.css` file. You can add your css section there or create another css file and include from theme.liquid template.
3. JS

   - Similar like of CSS, either create a new js file or go adding with the theme js. with js it's better to create new js and include from theme.liquid.

I suggest you to first be familiar with the themes files then you will get to know how things are working together. Good luck.